# $find() returns null when grid is in edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a control which is based on the Telerik RadComboBox that I'm trying to get with the ASP.NET AJAX function $find(), [as described in the Telerik docs.](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/overview)

```
var combo = $find('lookUp');  //ClientIDMode="Static"
```

I have two different pages that use the same grid which is based on the RadGrid. Although, the grids have different column definitions, in both cases the RadComboBox is inside an EditItemTemplate.

Both pages use the same MasterPage and are very similar.

My problem is, that on one page, $find() returns null but only if the grid is in edit mode. On the other page it works as expected even in edit mode.

While debugging I tried to call $find() inside IE's developer console with the same result. Even when I try to $find() the grid, it doesn't work in edit mode, but again, only that one page.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Any clues are appreciated.

Comment: Try to make sure there are no HTML tag mismatches, or other breaking javascript, which can throw this off...  also make sure you see the lookUp control in the markup of the page too.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I shifted some code around and finally noticed that the function I had referenced in the OnClientSelectedIndexChanged of the RadComboBox did not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting my code a bit further I noticed that the function that was referenced in the *OnClientSelectedIndexChanged* of the RadComboBox did not exist.

I've had copied the code from another solution and must have missed that one.